# Is there a length limit on how long an Apache environment variable can be?

Tags: apache-2.4, http, environment-variables

Is there something similar to LimitRequestFieldsize that applies a length limit to environment variable?

In other words, can one set environment variable value arbitrarily long or it will be truncated at certain limit? If there's none, is there any practical concern of setting a too long environment variable?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried it out to see what happens?

Comment: No I didn't...I would have thought if this is something documented in public domain I shouldn't have tried that out which involves setting up quite a bit just for testing. Though I couldn't find anything documented on that in apache docs.

Comment: You could spin up an EC2 instance and install Apache in 10 minutes, then another few minutes to try different lengths of variable quite easily. Agree that the documentation doesn't mention a limit.

Comment: Most likely it's going to be based on the OS limit, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078031/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-an-environment-variable-value

Comment: @DerK I think they are different concepts according to: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/env.html